# After upgrading to 22.04,ethernet not work,wifi works fine?

Tags: ethernet, 22.04

currently,lspci gives:

```
.....
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 10)
 Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
3c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
.....
```

As you can,both ethernet and wifi got listed,but only wifi works.If disabling wifi,I got:

[image: not wired networked got shown]

As we can see,no ethernet got listed.and before upgrading,after disable wifi entry like "Ethernet ..." will be in this list.After running "lshw -c network",these got printed out:

```
[sudo] password for alex: 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 64:5d:86:ba:09:af
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-40-generic firmware=46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- ip=192.168.8.119 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:ad414000-ad417fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
       logical name: enp60s0
       version: 10
       serial: 30:9c:23:ff:fb:a4
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=5.15.0-40-generic duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:ad200000-ad23ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

It seems the ehternet card of Killer E2500 got listed.Question is

How to make ethernet work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These solved the problem.

```
> sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
> sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: After upgrading to 22.04 from 20.04 on Xubuntu, this worked for me! I ended up needing to run `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` instead though.